# Cannot Initialize a class using the Singleton Method

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I created a class that gets an instance of a Database connection. However I am getting an error saying the calling class is null. I will post my error below.

Now I have a working and non working version of this code. I first just jammed everything into a single class to get it up and running then started to clean it up which is when I ran into issues.

This class "createJobTicket" calls the instance of DataBaseConnectionDAO

```
public class createJobTicket {

    //private java.sql.Connection conn = null;
    //private java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
    private static DataBaseConnectionDAO databaseConnection = DataBaseConnectionDAO.getInstance();

    public static HSSFWorkbook getWorkbook(HSSFWorkbook workbook, Long id, Environment env){

     try{

         java.sql.Connection conn =  databaseConnection.getConnection();
         java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
          String sql;
          sql = "SELECT"
                    +" hillcresttooldie.T_PO.id po_id,"
                    +" hillcresttooldie.T_PO.DUE_DATE due_date,"
                    +" hillcresttooldie.T_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME customer_name,"
                    +" hillcresttooldie.T_PART.ID part_id,"
                    +" hillcresttooldie.T_PO_PART.PART_QUANTITY part_quantity,"
                    +" hillcresttooldie.T_PART.PART_NUMBER part_number,"
                    +" hillcresttooldie.T_PART.PART_DESCRIPTION part_description,"
                    +" hillcresttooldie.T_PART.PLASMA_HRS_PER_PART plasma_hrs,"
                    +" hillcresttooldie.T_PART.GRIND_HRS_PER_PART grind_hrs,"
                    +" hillcresttooldie.T_PART.MILL_HRS_PER_PART mill_hrs,"
                    +" hillcresttooldie.T_PART.BRAKEPRESS_HRS_PER_PART brakepress_hrs,"
                    +" hillcresttooldie.T_PART.LASER_HRS_PER_PART laser_hrs,"
                    +" hillcresttooldie.T_MATERIAL.MATERIAL_THICKNESS material_thickness"
                    +" FROM hillcresttooldie.T_PO"
                    +" join hillcresttooldie.T_PO_PART"
                    +" on hillcresttooldie.T_PO_PART.PO_ID = hillcresttooldie.T_PO.ID"
                    +" join hillcresttooldie.T_PART"
                    +" on hillcresttooldie.T_PART.ID = hillcresttooldie.T_PO_PART.PART_ID"
                    +" join hillcresttooldie.T_CUSTOMER"
                    +" on hillcresttooldie.T_PO.CUSTOMER_ID = hillcresttooldie.T_CUSTOMER.ID"
                    +" join hillcresttooldie.T_PART_MATERIAL"
                    +" on hillcresttooldie.T_PART.ID = hillcresttooldie.T_PART_MATERIAL.PARTS_ID"
                    +" join hillcresttooldie.T_MATERIAL"
                    +" on hillcresttooldie.T_PART_MATERIAL.materials_id = hillcresttooldie.T_MATERIAL.id"
                    +" where T_PO.id = '"+id+"'";

         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

         int index = 0;

         //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
          while(rs.next()){
             int po_id = rs.getInt("po_id");
             String due_date = rs.getString("due_date");
             String customer_name = rs.getString("customer_name");
             int part_id  = rs.getInt("part_id");
             int part_quantity = rs.getInt("part_quantity");
             String part_number = rs.getString("part_number");
             String part_description = rs.getString("part_description");
             BigDecimal plasma_hrs = rs.getBigDecimal("plasma_hrs");
             BigDecimal grind_hrs = rs.getBigDecimal("grind_hrs");
             BigDecimal mill_hrs = rs.getBigDecimal("mill_hrs");
             BigDecimal brakepress_hrs = rs.getBigDecimal("brakepress_hrs");
             BigDecimal laser_hrs = rs.getBigDecimal("laser_hrs");
             double material_thickness = rs.getDouble("material_thickness");


             //Create the Sheet
             String sheetName = index + "-" + customer_name + "-" + part_number;
             HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
             //Apply Template to the sheet
             generateTemplate.applyTemplate(workbook, sheet);


             sheet.getRow(1).createCell(1).setCellValue(po_id);
             sheet.getRow(5).getCell(3).setCellValue(customer_name);
             sheet.getRow(5).createCell(8).setCellValue(due_date);
             sheet.getRow(6).getCell(3).setCellValue(part_number);
             sheet.getRow(6).createCell(8).setCellValue(part_quantity);
             sheet.getRow(7).createCell(4).setCellValue(part_description);
             sheet.getRow(7).createCell(8).setCellValue(material_thickness);


             index++;
          }
          //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
          rs.close();
          stmt.close();
          conn.close();

       }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println("SQL Exeception thrown");
       }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();

       }//end try
    return workbook;

    }
```

You can notice that the following is commented out:

```
//private java.sql.Connection conn = null;
//private java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
```

This is because if I my IDE said:

```
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field conn
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field stmt
```

My DataBaseConnectionDAO looks like the following:

```
public class DataBaseConnectionDAO {

    @Inject
    private static Environment env;

    private static DataBaseConnectionDAO instance;

    // Step 1: JDBC props
     String DB_URL = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
     String USER = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username");
     String PASS = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password");
     java.sql.Connection conn = null;
     java.sql.Statement stmt = null;

    private DataBaseConnectionDAO() { }

    public static DataBaseConnectionDAO getInstance() {

        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (DataBaseConnectionDAO.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new DataBaseConnectionDAO();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public java.sql.Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SQLException {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        if (conn == null) {

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        }

        return conn;
    }

}


[DEBUG] com.htd.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Enter: com.htd.web.rest.PoResource.generateJobTicket() with argument[s] = [16, com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter$StatusExposingServletResponse@1424a144]
[ERROR] com.htd.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exception in com.htd.web.rest.PoResource.generateJobTicket() with cause = null
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.htd.web.rest.util.createJobTicket
    at com.htd.web.rest.PoResource.generateJobTicket(PoResource.java:332) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.htd.web.rest.PoResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cfcd338a.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.htd.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:58) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.htd.web.rest.PoResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4795e29.generateJobTicket(<generated>) [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:104) [metrics-servlet-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:291) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.htd.web.filter.CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter.java:34) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
```

error:

```
[DEBUG] com.htd.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Enter: com.htd.web.rest.PoResource.generateJobTicket() with argument[s] = [16, com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter$StatusExposingServletResponse@613cf2e]
[ERROR] com.htd.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exception in com.htd.web.rest.PoResource.generateJobTicket() with cause = null
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.htd.web.rest.util.createJobTicket
    at com.htd.web.rest.PoResource.generateJobTicket(PoResource.java:332) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.htd.web.rest.PoResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cfcd338a.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: You need to declare the variables as static too if you want them at class level (`private static java.sql.Connection conn = null;`).

Comment: Side note on code quality: try to break up your lengthy method into many small ones. And try to avoid using **static** where possible (it just makes unit test **hard**).

Comment: Are you sure the error is saying that DataBaseConnectionDao is null? Your singleton implementation is working fine... I only tested the implementation... so I can't judge other parts...

Comment: I added to error and had to shorten the code. I took out the working code because the post was to long.

Comment: @Keppil even if I do what you recommended I get the same error that I posted above. It is saying cannot create createJobTicket but I did not have the issue until I implemented the Singleton pattern.

Comment: @Jägermeister if I can figure out a way not to use static I would do it in a heart beat. I am currently breaking the code down, that is when I ran into this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start by understanding what this error message means:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.htd.web.rest.util.createJobTicket
```

When the JVM loads a class, it will complete any static initialization for that class, i.e. assign any values given to `static` fields and run any `static { ... }` blocks.  As this involves running Java code, this process may cause an exception to be thrown.  If an exception is thrown during a class's static initialization, the class loading will fail.  Java will wrap the exception in an `ExceptionInInitializerError` and throw that.  If you make a second attempt to load the same class, Java will flatly refuse to load it, and instead throw a `NoClassDefFoundError` with message `Could not initialize class ...`.

As this is the error you are seeing, I can only conclude that your `createJobTicket` class is failing its static initialization, and that the exception stacktrace above is not from the first time you attempt to use the `createJobTicket` class.  If, for example, your application is a web application, try restarting the web application container, trying again and seeing if you get a different error first time around.

The static initialization for your `createJobTicket` class is the following line:

```
    private static DataBaseConnectionDAO databaseConnection = DataBaseConnectionDAO.getInstance();
```

So your `DataBaseConnectionDAO.getInstance()` method must be throwing an exception.

The best way to avoid static initialization issues like this is to avoid static initialization altogether.  For example, in the following, we create a method `getDatabaseConnection()` which sets the `databaseConnection` field if it hasn't already been set, and additionally calls the DAO to return a JDBC `Connection` object:

```
    private static DataBaseConnectionDAO databaseConnection;

    private static java.sql.Connection getDatabaseConnection() {
        if (databaseConnection == null) {
            databaseConnection = DataBaseConnectionDAO.getInstance();
        }
        return databaseConnection.getConnection();
    }

    public static HSSFWorkbook getWorkbook(HSSFWorkbook workbook, Long id, Environment env){

     try{

         java.sql.Connection conn = getDatabaseConnection();
         // ...
```

This approach should stop your `createJobTicket` class from failing to complete static initialization.  However, please do not expect your code to immediately start working after doing this.  The change above goes no way to fix the exception that causes the static initialization to fail.  All it does is to make sure this exception only gets thrown after the class has been statically initialized.  If you then attempt to run your code, you should hopefully see the actual exception in your log, instead of the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

So, why would your `DataBaseConnectionDAO.getInstance()` method be throwing an exception?  My best guess is this:

```
@Inject
private static Environment env;
```

A few searches suggest that you can't use Spring to inject values into static fields like this, so perhaps you are getting a NullPointerException trying to look up values in an environment that is `null`.  However, I haven't looked into this fully so I don't guarantee that this actually is the problem.